# Как добавлять элементы в объект js?

Tags: javascript

Есть глобальные объект, который пытаюсь заполнять на фронте собирая данные из `checkbox` для отправки на север.

```
<input class="a" type="checkbox" name="garanty" value="true">
<input class="a" type="checkbox" name="power" value="10kVt">
<input class="a" type="checkbox" name="power" value="5kVt">
```

JS

```
var filter_data = {
    items: []
};


$('.a').change(function(){

    if (this.checked == true) {

        var attr_data = [];

        filter_data.items.push({
          taxonomy: this.name,
          terms: attr_data,
        });      

        attr_data.push(this.value);

     console.log(filter_data.items);

    }


  });
```

На выходе должен быть обьект для php

```
    $obj = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'movie_janner',
            'terms'    => array( 'action', 'comedy' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'terms'    => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
        )
    );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qvr75jyu/7/

Comment: у вас там просто синтаксическая ошибка ( для начала )

Comment: @ThisMan - https://jsfiddle.net/qvr75jyu/7/ обнвоил

Comment: вы и код в вопросе обновите и ссылку ( комментарии не все читают )

Comment: @ThisMan уже обновил

Comment: ну и в чем конкретно проблема? Данные записываются, список выводится. То что вы представили как ответ, во первых на `php`, во вторых ни как не соотносится с той версткой, которая в вопросе. Что за `NOT IN` и откуда это взять из верстки?

Comment: @ThisMan поправил вопрос. Мне нужно доисывать terms в массив , а сейчас при изменении состояния чекбокса я создаю новый. С name power 2 раза,  а нужно один раз power и два terms ( 5kVt и 10kVt)

Comment: Так поменяйте у нужного инпута `name` на `terms`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var filterData = {
  items: []
};


$('.a').change(function(){

  if (this.checked == true) {
    
    // в js принят camelCase
    const attrData = [];
    let filterItem = filterData.items.find(el =>
      el.taxonomy === this.name
    );
    
    // проверяем, если у нас уже объект с таким именем
    if(filterItem) {
      filterItem.terms.push(this.value);
    } else {
      filterData.items.push({
        taxonomy: this.name,
        terms: [this.value],
      })
    }

    console.log(filterData.items);
  } else {
    // тут по идее нужно обработать 'выключение' чекбокса, но это если вам нужно
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="a" type="checkbox" name="garanty" value="true">
<input class="a" type="checkbox" name="power" value="10kVt">
<input class="a" type="checkbox" name="power" value="5kVt">
```